# Will conventional programs run on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I'm verry happy about the massage, that we will get a tablet version for Ubuntu!

Now I ask myself if the conventional programs like LibreOffice, OpenOffice, VLC Player, Thunderbird or other run on Ubuntu tablet? Or will be there the same Problems like Windows has with Windows RT, that it is required to have a version of the program that is programmed only for tablets.

Comment: Good for you about the massage... envy...

Answer (score 0):

The answer of that question may decide the Ubuntu role in tablets market. So far, only the windows 8 tablet has an office software on tablet market. If Ubuntu comes with a whole LibreOffice suite on their tablets, it could be a hit, a big hit!

Everybody wants to use their tables as notebooks, the big problem is the keyboard and, mainly, the office suit.

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to the CPU architecture used in the tablet. Most likely it will be ARM .

In this case software will need to be recompiled/ported. With open-source software this is easy (most of the software will compile with no problems in ARM architecture), but with closed-source software you will need to wait for the developer to build it on ARM.

If the tablet runs on a x86 CPU, existing software should work (though it might not be tablet-ready).